# Alter PublicPath in webpack with out rebuilding

Tags: webpack

Is it possible to modify publicPath with out rebuiilding a project?

My project may or may not be access behind a proxy, so I need to modify the baseurl with out recompiling the whole project.

I've looked in to `__webpack_public_path`;
[documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/); however this option does not persist when the project is built.

Comment: when you tried to add `__webpack_public_path`, have you done like the doc site? Using DefinePlugin and process.env variables?

Comment: Adding the process.env portion will only affect the initial build, subsequent changes will have no affect to it

Comment: Won't, because that thing is evaluated during build time, there is no way to dynamically update that since that code runs on the browser. You must update __webpack_public_path manually. There is no other way.